# in Vue template, space and new line between element tags are not ignored

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>
            hello world
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Output:
`<p> hello world </p>`

The space before and after "hello world" is not wanted. How can the spaces be remove through webpack or lint?

**vue.config.js**

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.module
            .rule('vue')
            .use('vue-loader')
            .tap(options => {
                options.compilerOptions.whitespace = "condense"
                merge(options, {
                    optimizeSSR: false
                })
            }); 
...
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with a newly created Vue app. What encoding do you have on your SFC file? Do you have `preserveWhitespace: true` in your Vue config file?

Comment: I am not sure what encoding I have on SFC. I have add my compilerOptions in Vue confige file above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely your use of the `whitespace: condense` setting in your Vue config.

According to the docs (https://cnpmjs.org/package/vue-template-compiler):

> If set to 'condense':
> Consecutive whitespaces inside a non-whitespace-only text node are condensed into a single space.

As this isn't a 'defaut setting' on a new Vue app I'd suggest removing it and seeing if that resolves the issue.